# HTML Form in table breaks the table - IE9

Tags: html, layout

Hi

I have HTML table of documents, 

each row is a document has link to download - so i added html form to each cell (frmDocuments_17 for example)

each row has check box so you can remove some documents in one shot - so I surrounded the table with HTML form (frmRemDocuments)


In Firefox the table displayed as expected, but in IE9 the first line breaks,

Any idea how to resolve this?


 here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/54s3C/

if you remove the external form it will display correctly

 Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You generally don't start a new form inside an existing form. IE is bugged, as we all know, so it's probably trying to close your previous form, but there are other open tags, so it's probably trying to close them all and then reopen them. Notice how the first cell in the third row is longer, that's because IE started a *new table* and it's not following the width of the previous rows.

Comment: IE-slamming aside, forms are not meant to be nestable. Instead of wrapping an anchor with a form, handle the click and submit a standalone form (a form not nested with the outer form).

Comment: I agree with jim here, perhaps if you could let us know what you're trying to accomplish we can suggest an alternate solution?

Comment: I am just trying to display some documents in html table to allow the user to download them (one by one) and delete them (many at once)

Comment: Is this IE bug, or my code is wrong? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested HTML forms was the problem,

Once I removed the nested forms code in IE works fine

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This was what I found in my case as well.